# RTL8821CE driver malfunctioning

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

I just bought a Lenovo ideapad S130 141GM and installed Ubuntu Budgie 19.04.
The wifi chip is a rtl8821ce so i had to install a driver with the commands :

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall git dkms build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
    git clone https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce
    cd rtl8821ce
    chmod +x dkms-install.sh
    chmod +x dkms-remove.sh
    sudo ./dkms-install.sh`

After rebooting, it worked, i could see many networks, **but not my box**. After that i used a wifi dongle with a RTL8188EUS which worked directly out of the box and saw the same networks **and my box**.

My box is working on channel 6, so it is not a problem of country channel allocation. The signal level o my box is of course much higher than the signal of all others networks and there is no other network on channel 6 (I tried on other channel without success too). My provider is "Free".

Does somebody have the same problem solved and could give me a hint of where to look (I would be happy to be able to use again the usb connector occupied by the wifi dongle) ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is "but not my box"? Uninstall your current dkms driver and try this one... https://github.com/shubham151/rtl8821ce. (git clone https://github.com/shubham151/rtl8821ce.git). Don't follow the ReadMe there for how to install it, rather, follow the same procedure that you did before so that you get the dkms install. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema

my box means the wifi i get from my provider (sorry, im french and don't know exactly what the name is in english for the ADSL interface you have at home).
I'll try your suggestion and tell you what happens.-Frank

Comment: @heinema 
Well there is a small problem :
frank@frank-Lenovo-ideapad-S130-14IGM:~$ git clone github.com/shubham151/rtl8821ce.git
fatal: le dépôt 'github.com/shubham151/rtl8821ce.git' n'existe pas

Comment: Correct command should be `git clone https://github.com/shubham151/rtl8821ce.git`

Comment: What is your MTU set to in your network connection script?

Comment: my box = wireless ADSL router

Comment: `https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/DS119359`

Comment: @heinema It works with the new driver ... Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments...

Uninstall your current dkms driver (https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce)...

```
cd rtl8821ce          # old source folder
sudo ./dkms-remove.sh # uninstall old dkms driver
```

And try this one... https://github.com/shubham151/rtl8821ce. (git clone https://github.com/shubham151/rtl8821ce.git). Don't follow the ReadMe there for how to install it, rather, follow the same procedure that you did before, so that you get the dkms install.

```
git clone https://github.com/shubham151/rtl8821ce.git # git clone new driver
cd rtl8821ce             # new source folder
chmod +x dkms-install.sh # make executable
chmod +x dkms-remove.sh  # make executable
sudo ./dkms-install.sh   # install new dkms driver
```

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu 20.04 this should do the trick:

```
apt install rtl8821ce-dkms
```