# 20:04 Studio: Installed but WiFI fails

Tags: networking, wireless, hp

I got an HP [17-BY2012NA](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c06604750) with these specs:

CPU: Intel core 15 quad core
speed/mem/max 600/400/4200 mghz
kernel: 5.4.0-26-low latency x86_64
SSD: 256 GB
OS: Ubuntu Studio 20.04

I got it installed but it's not seeing the WiFi. Any ideas? I'm doing this for a friend btw, so I can't post his system data here.

Comment: What you got installed?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: @K7AAY The script is an overkill for a newbie and is not necessary in 90% of cases.

Comment: @SoundShaman, please skip running the script I suggested earlier, and substitute the command line from _Pilot6_ .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Wi-Fi driver for Realtek RTL8821CE on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071299/how-to-install-wi-fi-driver-for-realtek-rtl8821ce-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Answer (score 0):

Realtek RTL8821CE is the problem.

From the answer [RTL8821CE driver malfunctioning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1189556/rtl8821ce-driver-malfunctioning):

```
git clone https://github.com/shubham151/rtl8821ce.git
cd rtl8821ce
chmod +x dkms-install.sh
chmod +x dkms-remove.sh
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

Comment: how do you know it's RTL8821CE?

Comment: Perhaps the HP support page linked from the first line of the question, which states "Wireless connectivity
Realtek RTL8821CE 802.11b/g/n/ac (1x1) and Bluetooth® 4.2 Combo" in the 10th line of the Hardware section?

Comment: @Pilot6 The OP links the specs of his PC. This is the card listed there.