# First time using ubuntu, Wi-Fi problems i don't understand how to solve

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

I wanted to switch over to Ubuntu because I don't really fancy Windows. But as the careful coward I am I decided to install Ubuntu 20.04 on a virtual machine on a scrap computer, before I attempt on my Main one. There was no problem at all, everything worked. So I installed it as the main and only OS on that same scrap computer, still, everything worked, Wi-Fi loaded up in the initial setup and all. So I thought "Hey, I'm good to go" and installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my Main HP computer, only to realize that the Wi-Fi doesn't work.

I have searched for many hours now and the most I can find doesn't really help me since most people already have all those needed packages downloaded and installed. I've tried to follow step-by-step guides by other people here but can't really install or do anything. I have no ethernet-wired-connection so that's not an option either. I do know that my wireless network thingy is called **RTL8821CE**, which from what I've read has no "official" drivers on Ubuntu, and none over like Ubuntu 18.04... Also can't do that github clone thing. All forums and all webpages says to do different stuff and now I'm just confused as to which commands to which things.

So what do you suggest? Can I download every separate package from github and packages.ubuntu.com and transfer them via USB? Is it possible at all to connect to Wi-Fi with the RTL8821CE on Ubuntu 20.04 or do I need to downgrade to 18.04? Is it even possible to downgrade?

Comment: Does the wifi work when you boot the USB stick? If so, you might try re-installing. This time, make sure you ask it to downĺoad updates as the installation proceeds. Maybe it's just an updated driver. Also, be sure you get the extra drivers -- there's a check box for that somewhere near the start of the installation, iirc.

Comment: @fbnickel What do you mean if Wi-Fi work when I boot the USB stick? I have tried re-installing it several timmes but nothing's different. I've also tried checking and unchecking the boxes in the installation about updates, SecureBoot etc. because of what I read from different other peoples posts on here. I also tried to disable SecureBoot in BIOS because someone said that had to be disabled for some terminal commands regarding meteorit to work or something

Comment: Perhaps you can tether to your phone for temporary network access, using either a USB cable or Bluetooth connection. Perhaps a friend will lend you a WiFi USB dongle or ethernet-USB dongle for temporary network access. The accepted answer in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1189556/rtl8821ce-driver-malfunctioning is --by far-- the best advice to follow.

Comment: During the installation, you're prompted to set up your wifi. You have to choose an SSID and enter the wifi password. You're using the machine's wifi hardware at that point. If it works there, it will work after everything is installed. Well. Logic says so, at least.

Comment: @fbnickel yeah that doesn't happen on this computer. It did on the old scrap one tho.

Comment: @user535733 i tried sharing internet from my iPhone to the computer and it just said "Wired Connected" but I still couldn't access the internet and the connection-symbol that appeared in the top shell has a question mark on top, but no interactions can be made

Comment: I managed to successfully get on the internet through USBcable from my phone, so I could download dkms and all that jazz. Through following the guide provided above in this thread, i now have proper working wifi on both my computers with Ubuntu 20.04! Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Good work. Glad it all worked out.